# Recreating existing map using leaflet, javascript, and html: highlighting regions

Tags: javascript, html, svg, leaflet

I am trying to recreate an existing map (with permission of course): https://kaart.slimnetwerk.be/leden in order to learn how to use leaflet. My goal is to highlight only some of the regions, for instance only Vilvoorde. The reason I want to work on the existing map, is that I really like how all the borders are indicated (using svg file and paths), and I want to use a selection of the same regions for my project.

However, when I download the webpage (and its related files) and open the html file in my browser -Google Chrome-, the highlighted regions are gone. When I try to zoom out or move the map, the regions sometimes appear in the background (but not necessarely in the right position).
Am I doing something wrong with the download?

Should I have other files available (the download gave me the images for svg, the html code, stylesheets (members.css, leaflet.css), and js files (jquery.js.download, leaflet.js.download, members-min.js.download).